# Dos Command rename folders and subfolders with special characters

Tags: dos, file-rename, batch-rename

How can I remove the special character using DOS Command on folder and subfolders?

Folders:

```
C:\FILE\FOLDER#1\PICTURE#100

C:\FILE\FOLDER#2\PICTURE#200

C:\FILE\FOLDER#3\PICTURE#300

C:\FILE\FOLDER#4\PICTURE#400

C:\FILE\FOLDER#5\PICTURE#500
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\FILE\FOLDER1\PICTURE100

C:\FILE\FOLDER2\PICTURE200

C:\FILE\FOLDER3\PICTURE300

C:\FILE\FOLDER4\PICTURE400

C:\FILE\FOLDER5\PICTURE500
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually using an old version of MS-DOS (in that case, which version?) or the command prompt  in Windows? The "#" isn't a special character in ``cmd`` so you can just rename each file or folder at a time using ``ren <old-name> <new-name>``
Or are you asking how to automate that process for all files and folders?

Comment: The folder names are more than 8 characters long - must be Windows.

Comment: im using Windows 7 Command Prompt. i just want to remove this character "#" to all folders and sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on some sample folders first.  It will rename two levels of folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "c:\file"
for /d %%z in (*) do (
  pushd "%%z"
     for /d %%a in (*) do (
         set "folder=%%a"
         ren "%%a" "!folder:#=!"
     )
  popd
)    
for /d %%a in (*) do (
     set "folder=%%a"
     ren "%%a" "!folder:#=!"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --find "#" **
```

Removes the "#" from all files and folders recursively